# Undo moved branch in GitX

Tags: git, branch, gitx

I accidentally moved a branch in GitX (drag&drop using the mouse) onto another branch.
Now, both branch labels point at the same tip(!) and I cannot see the commits done on the moved branch.

Using `git reflog` I wanted to see that change and undo it, but nothing got logged.

What is the recommended way (graphical or in terminal) to undo that move operation from GitX? Menu->Edit->Undo does not offer going back.

(Background: I thought that the move operation would also carry the commits, i.e., like a rebase, but it doesn't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding: 
You had

```
A-B-C  master
 \D-E develop
```

You then accidentally moved develop on commit C (same as master).

You then get

```
A-B-C (master, develop)
 \D-E
```

If you want to move branch "develop" back to "commitE", you should use the [git branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) command:

```
git branch -f <branch-name> <starting-point>
```

The command has to be used when your HEAD is on another branch.
So in the example above, I would do:

```
git checkout master
```

So that my HEAD is located on branch "master", 
followed by

```
git branch -f develop commitE
```

This should switch you back to your initial state, i.e.

```
A-B-C  master
 \D-E develop
```

Comment: Well explained, thank you! I followed your advice and got my original branch back :) I'd like to add that in this case the original branch commit (commitE in your case) can only retrieved browsing the reflog.